# monaco.editor.colorize throw an exception when html includes script tag

Tags: javascript, monaco-editor

Following code throw an exception.

```
console.log(monaco.editor.colorize("<script>a = 1</script>", "html"))
```

A error message is here.

```
TypeError: this._embeddedModes.hasOwnProperty is not a function
```

I use this version: https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/monaco-editor/0.18.0/min/vs/loader.js

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/tndefzsu/)

What is wrong?

Comment: Hi @blz, can you please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your problem? Using the monaco-editor [playground](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/playground.html) the code `monaco.editor.create(document.getElementById("container"), {
 value: "<script>a = 1</script>",
 language: "html"
});` seems to work just fine.

Comment: I'm getting the same error, have not tracked down the solution yet. It's when using the `colorize` method...

Comment: Referenced this stackoverflow question and filed an issue report on monaco-editor github: https://github.com/microsoft/monaco-editor/issues/1649
This was working in previous releases, and I don't see any notes in the changelog, so it seems like something has broken.